# Restore a deleted user on Mac via command line

Tags: terminal, user-account

I'm trying to add a user based on an backed-up home folder via command line.

I have tried the UI approach documented by apple at [Restore a deleted user on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp2968/mac). This works but I need to do this as part of a script.

I am unable to get this to work via command line using the `sysadminctl` tool. The steps I have tried are:

1. Manually create the existing home folder at `/Users/foo` from a deleted user's home folder using [Apple's instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp2968/mac) - I plan to automate this later.
2. Use `sysadminctl -addUser`:

```
sudo sysadminctl -addUser foo -fullName foo -password some_password -home
```

or...

```
sudo sysadminctl -addUser foo -fullName foo -password some_password -home /Users/foo
```

After doing either of the above I'm able to login to the new account but there are many issues:

- I do not seem to have access to any folders.
- Services such as spotlight and others ask for the keychain password. The passwords I enter do not work.
- The desktop has the wrong image for the user I'm restoring from and it is missing a folder.

See screenshot with arrows pointing to some obvious issues:

[image: screenshot]

**Edited** for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have solved the issue. It seems to be related to file permissions. Instead of manually copying the existing home folder (step 1 in the question), I copied using `ditto` which seems to have preserved the correct permissions.

```
sudo ditto /Users/foo-deleted /Users/foo
```